# Unable to export data to excel sheet using tabulator plugin

Tags: javascript, excel, tabulator

I am using [Tabulator](http://tabulator.info/) Plugin to load my data into my html. For that I am using this code in my javascript:

```
 var j = $( "#example-table" ).hasClass( "tabulator" )
  console.log(res["data"]);

  if (j) {
    $("#example-table").tabulator("destroy");


  }
  $("#example-table").tabulator({
    layout:"fitColumns"});

  //set new columns
  $("#example-table").tabulator("setColumns", res["column"]);

  //set new data
  $("#example-table").tabulator("setData", res["data"]);


  $("#download-xlsx").click(function(){
    $("#example-table").tabulator("download", "xlsx", "data.xlsx");
  });

  $("#download-csv").click(function(){
    $("#example-table").tabulator("download", "csv", "data.csv");
});

//trigger download of data.json file
$("#download-json").click(function(){
    $("#example-table").tabulator("download", "json", "data.json");
});
```

And I am using this code in my html:

```
    <div>
    <button class ="table-button" id ="download-xlsx">Download XLSX</button>
    <button class ="table-button" id ="download-csv">Download CSV</button>
    <button class ="table-button" id ="download-pdf">Download PDF</button>
    <button class ="table-button" id ="download-json">Download JSON</button>
    </div>

     <div id="example-table" style="margin-bottom: 100px; margin-top: 30px;" ></div>
    </div>
```

This code is working fine each time on ajax call I am fetching data using res["data"] I am putting this into tabulator set data function and it is loading my data perfectly. But when I am clicking on download excel first time when I load data I am downloading on file but when I cilck and reload new data it gdownload three files or four files. My question is how to reset files and download queue when I click on new my new data.

Answer (score 0):

There is no download queue in Tabulator, if you click the button it will download the table contents.

If you are getting multiple downloads happening that suggests that you are rebinding your click event several times so on click of the button is calling the function multiple times.

Comment: so how to fix that